# When I click on the activity I have 3 Text View in that. I want to load the Text View one after another like after a gap of 2 seconds?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, textview, thread-sleep

I am not sure but my research led me to come to this point. I think I need to create Thread object and then I can use `Thread.sleep(seconds);` But I am not sure how it works with Text View.

```
  private void runThread() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (i++ < 2) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFirst);
                            TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSecond);
                            TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvThird);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

This is not even responding. I know I am doing wrong here but this is all what I can think of right now. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your code does nothing. What is the expect behavior?

Comment: what do you actually expect your code to do??? after 0.3 secs it only find the textviews through their id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Handler.postDelayed** . Example:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
     public void run(){
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSecond);
                        tv2.setText("I set this text after waiting for 2 seconds");

                    }
                });

      }
 },2000);
```

This will update your second textView after two seconds. You can do pretty much the same with the others.